# Can I download iTunes?

Tags: music, itunes

Is there anyway of using iTunes? Or anything I can download that would work with an iPhone so I can put music on an iPhone?

Comment: I run iTunes in Windows 7 in a virtual machine.  Haven't found another solution that works reliably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/414737/how-do-i-install-itunes-on-ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way would be to run a virtual instance of Windows using Oracle's VirtualBox (install through Software Centre or [download it](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)). You could try Wine, too, but [iTunes on Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) is only rated 'bronze', which means it probably won't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Clementine bills itself as a substitute for iTunes that allows you to load music an on iOS device.

https://www.clementine-player.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Last I played with Apple(the iPhone 3) I used the [libimobiledevice-dev](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/):

`sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-dev`

Reference:

- [libimobiledevice - A cross-platform software library and tools to communicate with iOS devices natively](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libimobiledevice-dev/)
- [Ubuntu – Details for package libimobiledevice-dev in trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libimobiledevice-dev)