# Mounting an iPad Documents folder in 15.04

Tags: mount, 15.04, 16.04, ipad, ios

My desktop computer runs Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet. I have an iPad2 running iOS 8.4.

I have installed libimobiledevice 1.2 and ifuse 1.1.2

When I connect my iPad to the computer, the system only detects an "iPad" folder, but the Document folder that used to appear when mounting the iDevices is not there. Rhythmbox and Shotwell work fine, though.

Can someone shed a little bit of light there? I've been using some of the apps' WiFi upload capabilities, but it's too slow when transferring big media files.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: did you unlock your ipad screen when connecting?

Comment: Yes, I did.

I rebooted both the iPad and the computer after installing the latest version of libimobiledevice and iFuse, I unlocked the iPad, and I selected "Trust this computer" when the iPad asked me.

And as I said, I can access the "iPad" directory, where I can see the DCIM directory, and the other iPad standard directories and databases. 

What I can't see is the "Documents" folder that used to be mounted along the iPad folder one, that allowed me to enter each app's directory and see the files in there, and move those between my computer and the iPad.

Comment: Same here with 14.04 and libimobiledevice 1.2.

Comment: Also, same behavior with an 8.3 and iOS9 device. Only one shows up.

Comment: Does http://itsfoss.com/mount-iphone-ipad-ios-7-ubuntu-13-10/#comment-1268303764 or http://askubuntu.com/q/598940/186134 help?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. All the installed versions of libimobiledevice and ifuse are newer than the ones mentioned in the article.

The article is also one year old and refers to iOS 7, which I did managed to mount flawlessly in Ubuntu.

We're talking iOS 8 and 9 here, and the iPad folder mounts properly. What doesn't mount is the Documents folder, which leads me to believe that the problem is iFuse, not libimobiledevice.

Comment: Sounds like Apple has done something with iOS 8/9 and might need the attention of the developers of ifuse and libimobiledevice. Apple is just like that, locking down devices, or maybe they implemented a new file transfer protocol.

Answer (score 3):

***Update:*** This now has a GUI, check it out [here](http://tunesviewer.sourceforge.net/ios-transfer-made-easier/).

This worked for iOS 8.3 device:

1) According to [this](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=15023.0) it needs new ifuse install that matches libimobiledevide. According to this the --documents command was [added in 1.1.3](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse/blob/master/NEWS) and the version in Ubuntu is 1.1.2. So, I downloaded the ifuse-1.1.3.tar.bz2 [from the site](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/).

2) Install fuse library or configure will complain: `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev build-essential`

3) Run `./configure` in the unzipped folder, then `make` and `make install` as described in the readme file.

4) Verify it upgraded by running `ifuse --version` (1.1.3)

5) Add yourself to fuse users:

```
sudo modprobe fuse
sudo adduser $USER fuse
```

and log out, log back in.

---- *(The GUI linked above will run the steps below, much easier)* ----

6) Create a folder to mount an app's documents, say, `mkdir /tmp/vlctest/`

7) To connect to the VLC app for example, run `ifuse --documents org.videolan.vlc-ios /tmp/vlctest/`

8) When done, unmount with `fusermount -u /tmp/vlctest`

Unfortunately the ideviceinstaller isn't compiling for me, even with `libzip-dev` installed. It apparently hasn't been updated for recent libimobiledevice in a loong time.

Comment: It doesn't let me install it, it says I don't have libimobiledevice 1.0 or posterior, while I have already installed 1.2

Comment: @OriolFM What says you don't have "libimobiledevice 1.0 or posterior"??

Comment: @NoBugs It says `configure: error: Package requirements (libimobiledevice-1.0 >= 1.0.0) were not met: No package 'libimobiledevice-1.0' found` on Ubuntu 15.10 with libimobiledevice6 installed using deb from 16.04.

Comment: I resolved the error by installing `libimobiledevice-dev` from 16.04 packages (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/libimobiledevice)

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Dont you mean installing dev files *and* compiling latest 1.2?

Comment: @NoBugs I did not compile 1.2, I installed it from 16.04 packages. It is called `libimobiledevice6`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 16.04 `ideviceinstaller` doesn't work, and it was difficult to find the APPIDs. I found a workaround by installing `libimobiledevice-utils` and running `idevicesyslog` while opening the app.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky What do you mean, ideviceinstaller doesn't work? You would have to have a properly signed .ipa for your idevice to install on it, correct?

Comment: I meant it cannot list installed apps, so I did not know what parameter to use for `ifuse --documents`

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky are you trying `ifuse --documents` with ifuse 1.1.3?

Comment: Yes """"""""""""

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Why don't you get the App ids from the application linked above, or using the Python example here: https://github.com/upbit/python-imobiledevice_demo