# How can I write a review for an item on iTunes on Ubuntu?

Tags: itunes

I would like to leave a [review](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201991) for a podcast on iTunes. However, I don't have any Apple device, nor access to the iTunes software.

Is there any other solution to leave a review for an item on iTunes from a Ubuntu system?

Comment: If their policy is to not let users review a device that you do not have I doubt we should consider this a problem that is fixabled through Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't detailed on the support pages, I doubt you could do it. Given Apple's unwillingness to support Linux users on all products is highly possible that there isn't a way unless [you install iTunes](https://askubuntu.com/q/414737/169736), and even then, the store may not be available at all.