# Itunes Wine installation

Tags: wine, itunes

Has anyone actually been able to run Itunes on Ubuntu 14?  And If so what version Itunes did you use.  I cannot run as far back as 11.4.0  it says windows error 126. Or it shows a blank Itunes template.

Comment: winehq says no - https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347

Comment: It will not work.  You will have to run a Windows virtual machine if you need itunes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install iTunes on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414737/how-do-i-install-itunes-on-ubuntu) Just like [the only answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/739108/250300), it recommends PlayOnLinux.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with PlayOnLinux just clicking on its built-in iTunes installer. I believe these are the versions that worked for me, but again you should install via PlayOnLinux:

- Ubuntu 14.04 with Wine 1.4.1 (32-bit) and [iTunes 10.1.1 (32-bit)](http://www.oldapps.com/itunes.php?old_itunes=69)
- Ubuntu 15.10 with Wine 1.7.48 (32-bit) and [iTunes 12.0.1 (32-bit)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1790?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

I only ever used it for purchasing music, however. I would not expect it to work for syncing music to an Apple device.