# How can I run iTunes or shareit?

Tags: boot

Ubuntu is awesome fun amazing innovative and many other things.  but I hate that it does not support itunes or shareit. How can I run iTunes or shareit? What would happen if I downloaded the software from their web sites?

Comment: There is no itunes for Ubuntu so it does nothing, don't bother!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have the situation reversed: it is the vendors of the software who do not support Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can install i tunes on Ubuntu through wine or playonlinux, i will insert a link to the website that will assist you in the installation.
please note that this is a port which means there might be some bugs and crashes, so what i mean to say is it will work with some difficulty

Here is the links:

**This is the play on Linux tutorial site:** 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-install-itunes-ubuntu-1410-1604-sam-khaukha

**Here is an similar question to yours:**
[How do I install iTunes on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414737/how-do-i-install-itunes-on-ubuntu)

> 1. Install PlayOnLinux.
>
>    sudo apt-get install playonlinux
> 2. Open PlayOnLinux and type iTunes in the search bar. You will find the several versions of iTunes.
> 3. Select the version that you want to install.
> 4. You will see the Installation Wizard popup dialog box. You will be informed about the iTunes version and the location of the installation.
>      Click on *Next* to install.
> 5. PlayOnLinux will now download the iTunes installer.
> 6. You will see installation widget for iTunes. Click *Next* and follow the installation procedure.
> 7. After few seconds, iTunes will be installed.

**Here is an you tube video:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZuAIMBuxVM

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference :)