# Itunes black screen issue

Tags: apple, itunes

I’ve just downloaded iTunes on my Ubuntu and it’s working but it appears as a black screen  any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You're likely running iTunes via WINE.  Try a newer version of WINE.  If that doesn't help, it'll likely never work.   Apple is constantly changing iTunes so that it doesn't work with WINE.

Comment: iTunes via WINE doesn't work right even if up to date.

Comment: Related: [How do I install iTunes on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/414737/250300)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use iTunes version 12.9.3 and older (32-bit). It doesn't work with newer versions of iTunes.

I highly recommend using the installation procedure described here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SVgGX9x1hWZzyhEJs5_7UH1K5i7Cuz6B2iuIwm40VrQ

Answer (score 0):

I am on Manjaro and just got the same problem. Tried different versions and installers - including ones specifically for windows 8, cause the newer ones complained that I need windows 10.

The final one that I managed to install successfully was version 12.9.5.7. I downloaded it from downloads.digitaltrends.com/itunes/windows.
(Strongly hope there is no virus in it :D ...)

Also worth mentioning is that actually I need it for deploying flutter testing apps to an old iPhone that I have ... I don't want it for listening music.

But anyway - hope this version works for you too.